# Port forwarding Openstack landscape

Tags: networking, maas, openstack

I have install MAAS+OpenStack on My servers.
At the end of install OpenStack Autopilot, I got adress to interface of Openstack Landscape:  http://10.1.1.102/account/standalone/openstack

How can I do port forwarding to see that from other LAN?

IP of main server with IP on word is (for example): 155.158.102.80 where is MAAS page on http://155.158.102.80/MAAS/

I have created something like that but I don't now is it good:

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 155.158.102.80 --dport 33333  -j DNAT -to 10.1.1.102:80

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openstack Landsacpe is in https connection so port forwarding for port 80 don't work.
I added this two iptables instructions and it works! ;)

sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 155.158.102.80 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.1.1.102:443
and
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.1.1.102--dport 443 -j ACCEPT

MAAS is working on http (80) so We can forward port 443 without problems.

Regards.